# Convert character string to number in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a character string to a number in R. Example:

```
a=1; b=2
```

If my input is "abba", I want my output to be a+b+b+a = 1+2+2+1 = 6.
Here's my attempt so far:

```
str= "abba"
paste(unlist(strsplit(unlist(str_extract_all(str, "[aA-zZ]+")), split = "")),collapse="+")
[1] "a+b+b+a"
```

I don't know how to convert this to numeric since as.numeric() returns NA. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option setting factor levels for the `letters` like this:

```r
str= "abba"
sum(as.numeric(factor(unlist(strsplit(str, "")), levels = letters)))
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `data.frame` to translate your letters to numbers, and `match` after using `strsplit`:

```
translation <- data.frame(letter = letters, 
                          number = 1:26)
str <- "abba"
sum(match(strsplit(str, "")[[1]], translation$letter))
#> [1] 6
```

Comment: Better use a named vector: `translation <- setNames(1:26, letters); sum(translation[strsplit(str, "")[[1]]])` Your solution doesn't use the translation table.

Comment: I believe the last line of code in the original answer should be 
`sum(translation$number[match(strsplit(str, "")[[1]], translation$letter)])`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `chartr`

```
eval(parse(text = chartr('ab', '12', gsub("(?<=\\w)(?=\\w)", "+",
    str, perl = TRUE))))
[1] 6
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution using gsub as well!